# Why is Juju unable to connect to environment?

Tags: juju, maas

I can bootstrap but I can't see the juju status.

```
Error details: 

    no instances found
```

This shows up when i juju --debug --show-log and I bootstrap MAAS but it shows environment is already bootstrap.

```
Juju -- devops distilled
https://juju.ubuntu.com/

Juju provides easy, intelligent service orchestration on top of environments
such as Amazon EC2, HP Cloud, OpenStack, MaaS, or your own local machine.

Basic commands:
  juju init             generate boilerplate configuration for juju environments
  juju bootstrap        start up an environment from scratch

  juju deploy           deploy a new service
  juju add-relation     add a relation between two services
  juju expose           expose a service

  juju help bootstrap   more help on e.g. bootstrap command
  juju help commands    list all commands
  juju help glossary    glossary of terms
  juju help topics      list all help topics

Provider information:
  juju help azure       use on Windows Azure
  juju help ec2         use on Amazon EC2
  juju help hpcloud     use on HP Cloud
  juju help local       use on this computer
  juju help openstack   use on OpenStack
2013-11-12 13:28:49 INFO juju supercommand.go:286 command finished
```

This is debug -v status

```
2013-11-12 13:33:52 DEBUG juju.provider.maas environprovider.go:33 opening environment "maas".
2013-11-12 13:33:52 DEBUG juju state.go:160 waiting for DNS name(s) of state server instances []
2013-11-12 13:33:52 DEBUG juju state.go:165 error getting state instances: no instances found
2013-11-12 13:33:52 ERROR juju supercommand.go:282 Unable to connect to environment "".
Please check your credentials or use 'juju bootstrap' to create a new environment.

Error details:
no instances found
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `juju --debug --show-log status`? Or `juju --debug -v status`?

Comment: Also, which provider, and if ec2, which region? Although since tagged maas, guessing maas, in which case the common error is wrong mongo installed. Can you ssh into the machine allocated for bootstrap and do 'apt-cache policy mongodb-server'?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you might not have DNS working to get to the Juju Boostrap node.

What do you have set in MaaS for"Default domain for new nodes" under "Network Configuration" on the settings page of MaaS?

What is the output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf`?

What is the IP address of your MaaS server?

If I'm right about the DNS being the problem, you'll need to run `sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` and then put in the line `nameserver <ip_of_your_maas_server>`, save the file, run `sudo resolvconf -u`, and then try the juju status command again.